# MVC'd login form

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc

I've written this small MVC login application as an example for someone, would anyone let me know what they think of it?

**index**

```
include("login_view.php");
include("login_model.php");
include("login_controller.php");

Login_view::show_login_form();
$Login_controller = new Login_controller();
$Login_controller->validate($conn);
```

**login_view**

```
class Login_view{
    static function show_login_form(){
        echo 
        "<form method=\"GET\" action=\"{$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]}\">
            Username: <input name=\"username\" type=\"text\"> </br>
            Password: <input name=\"password\" type=\"password\"> </br>
            <input name=\"login\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\">
        </form>";
    }

    static function show_message($message){
        echo $message;
   }

}
```

**login_controller**

```
    class Login_controller{
    function validate($conn){
        if( isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"]) ){
            if( !empty($_GET["username"]) and !empty($_GET["password"]) ){
                $Login_model = new Login_model($conn);
                if($Login_model->check_user_and_pass()){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION["username"] = "logged_in";
                    Login_view::show_message("logged in");
                }
            }else{
                Login_view::show_message("empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**login_model**

```
class Login_model{
    function __construct($conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
    function check_user_and_pass(){
        $select_user_pass_query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username, password = :password");

        if($select_user_pass_query->execute(array(':username'=>$_GET["username"], ':password'=>$_GET["password"]))){
            $details = $select_user_pass_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            if(!empty($details)){
                return true;
            }else{
                Login_view::show_message("Wrong user or password");
            }
        }else{
            Login_view::show_message("Error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MVC**

- the model shouldn't care where user input comes from, so it shouldn't work on `POST`, that's the job of the controller. To fix this, add arguments to `check_user_and_pass` which you pass from the controller. This makes your code more flexible and easier to read (`GET`, `POST` are only handled in the controller, not all over the place).
- the entry point should be the controller. It should decide what the view shows. If you always want to show the form, just add `Login_view::show_login_form();` to the top of `validate`. If it should only be displayed when not logged in, put it in the else clauses.
- I would make the view non-static. It doesn't really matter all that much, as it doesn't have a state, but the controller doesn't either, and it is non-static, so just for consistency it makes sense (also, it might make writing tests easier).

**Security**

- `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is user controller, and thus echoing it creates an XSS vulnerability. Either handle this a different way (empty action, etc), or use `htmlspecialchars`.
- use `POST` for logins instead of `GET`. It might happen that a user shares a link with their password still in the URL, a URL might be bookmarked or saved in the browser history, etc. It's also the correct way of handling it, because `GET` should only retrieve resources.

**Misc**

- all that escaping in the form makes it hard to read. If you use `'` instead of the outer `"`, you don't need to do it (be careful when doing it the other way around - `"` for the outer quotes, and `'` for the inner once - as `htmlspecialchars` doesn't encode `'` per default).
- variable names should be lower-case
- I would use `&&` instead of `and` in the PHP code and `AND` instead of `,` in SQL.
- class names are generally written in CamelCase.
- if you use guard clauses checking the arguments, you can safe one level of nesting and produce more readable code. Eg in `validate`, you might negate the outer if and return: `if( !isset($_GET["username"]) || !isset($_GET["password"]) ) { return; }`.
- having a session value called `username` which doesn't contain the username is a bit confusing. I would probably change it to `isLoggedIn` or something and then set it to true.

Comment: first statement, like this? controller.php check_user_and_pass($username, $pass)

Comment: @user2909036 yes, exactly. Then replace `$_GET["username"]` with `$username` (same for pass), and call it as `$Login_model->check_user_and_pass($_GET["username"], $_GET["password"])`.